# Store values from Sqlite database as it is returned

Tags: ios, sqlite

So, when i execute the query directly in sqlite it returns me the values in the order as I am expecting it to be. But when I display it on my iOS app, it sorts the values in ascending order which I don't want to happen. Can anybody help me to get over this problem?!

Thanks in advance!! :-)

Comment: How do you expect the ordering to be?

Comment: Say my query returns values like First, Second, Third and Fourth. When I display it on my app, it returns as First, Fourth, Second and Third where as I want it to be I, II, III and IV..

Comment: But what kind of sorting is this? I see no order in "First", "Second", "Third", and "Fourth". Neither in "I", "II", "III", and "IV". Please post some of the SQL you use to create the table, to insert values, and to query them.

Comment: oh ho... U are not getting my point.. Well, My query returns the output First, Second, Third, Fourth.. But when I execute it on iOS app, it just sorts it alphabetically.. First then Fourth instead of First then Second!! I am sorry the data I have in my DB is really huge.. Cant post query for them!!

Comment: Sorry, but if you don't add SQL and/or code, I can't help you.

Comment: Yes, I have faced this similar issue.. But don't have a solution yet.. Can anyone help me.. I will update the table structure and query shortly..

Comment: How are you displaying the values you've retrieved from the DB? How are you storing them?

Comment: I am storing it in an array.. @ott--

Comment: @Nina Fine. How are you displaying it from the array then? Show the contents of the array with `NSLog(@"array = %@", [myarray description]);`.

Comment: did you copy pass some code from somewhere else ? :-)

Comment: My table is one similar to this |Sl No|Column1|Column2| |1||d2ata|two |2|d1ata|one|  |3|d3ata|three|

Comment: I was teasing. More seriously it will help if you explain the structure you use to store your result. Basically your away - put some code snippet

Comment: if you follow the code snippet i provided you, you should be able to trace what is added within the mutable array. I still think that if you just provide / explain the code related to how you feed your array it will help otherwise there is not much we can do on stackoverflow...

Comment: I understand tiguero.I'll try to post a demo code asap!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has your query an "order by" statement? Maybe this way gives you the control to get the results as you want.

Comment: If you don't use "order by" then the order of the result is not guaranteed. The order the database returns the data in might change over time depending on changes in the database.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve shouldn't be a problem:

1. make your SQL query:
   it will probably looks like this `select columname from yourtable order by asc` asc will sort the result in alphabetic order if you want your result to be ordered
2. read the result of the SQL query line by line. Here is some code snippet to do so:

   ```
   NSString *SQLQuery  = @"your SQL query here" 

   // The SQL statement that you plan on executing against the database 
   const char *sql =  [SQLQuery UTF8String];

   // The SQLite statement object that will hold your result set 
   sqlite3_stmt *statement;

   // Prepare the statement to compile the SQL query into byte-code
   int sqlResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL);


   if (sqlResult== SQLITE_OK) {

       while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

       // feed the result in a mutable array here
       // e.g [yourmutablearray addObj: yourObj];

       }

       // Finalize the statement to release its resources
       sqlite3_finalize(statement);
   }
   else // catch up any possible issue here
   {
       NSLog(@"Problem excuting SQL statement on the Database:"); 
       NSLog(@"%d",sqlResult);
   }
   ```